Show or theatre that came on every Saturday morning in the Bay Area from the late 60s thru the 70s?
Back in the 60s-70s every Saturday morning, there was a show/theatre program that was dedicated to sci-fi and horror movies from the past.  Movies like Godzilla (all of them), Vincent Price movies, monster movies like Frankenstein, The Mummy, Werewolf, The Creature from the Black Lagoon, The Day the Earth Stood Still, 20 Million Miles to Earth, and so many more.  I kept thinking it was called "Science Fiction Theater" but I cannot find any reference to that name.  I'm also not sure if it was a local show, or maybe a national show?  I grew up in Sunnyvale, Ca. if it makes any difference.  I was raised on these movies and have influenced me and my imagination. In a good way!

There is a show called Science Fiction Theatre, but it's from the '50s and tells its own stories, rather than being dedicated to classic movies.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creature_Double_Feature?

Could this be Creature Features?
It aired in the Bay area in the 1960s onward, and showed all the films on your list above.

Creature Features is a program of horror shows broadcast on local American television stations throughout the 1960s, 1970s, and 1980s. The movies broadcast on these shows were generally classic and cult horror movies of the 1930s to 1950s, the horror and science-fiction films of the 1950s, British horror films of the 1960s, and the Japanese kaiju "giant monster" movies of the 1950s to 1970s.


Oh I remember Bob Wilkins from Creature Features. I believe that show came on in the evening. The show I’m thinking of was on first thing in the morning.

Suggesting this could be Fantastic Flick.
As described here:

"KTXL TV 40 Sacramento CA had Fantastic Flick first on Saturday Mornings at 10:30 then later to Saturday Afternoons at 2:pm in the 1970's."
"Fantastic Flick" was a horror / science fiction movie show with an announcer on KTXL-TV channel 40 in Sacramento, California, USA. The show ran at 2:00pm on Saturdays. The horror and science fiction movies tended to be a little more family friendly than what would be screened on late night horror movie shows

